# How to initialize log4j with spring and main method?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I have spring, log4j and config file for log4j. How to pass my config file to log4j and initialize it with spring? I've seen aproach with initialization in web.xml, but I have no servlet container so it doesen't work for me. I only have a main method.

Comment: Are you trying to do something more complicated than just having your `log4j.properties` on the classpath?

Comment: OMG. I've realized now that I could just initialize log4j in main method. I've just started with spring and didn't think of it in that way. My mistake. And thanx for clearing my mind:)

Comment: If you just grab your loggers in `private static final` variables, I think the magic happens automatically.

Comment: Also add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` system property when starting the program, or set it programmatically before log4j initialization: `System.setProperty("log4j.debug", "true");`. This will print to stdout the location at which properties file is looked for during initialization, and its content (loggers, appenders, ...)